# How to put image on top of image in HTML/CSS? Nothing's working

Tags: html, css

I am trying to take one image, place it on the screen as a background, and then put a company logo on top of it so it all looks like one image.  I have looked at other people's examples, and those give me the background where I want it, but the company logo that I want on top of the background is displayed beside the background instead of on top.  Nothing I try seems to be working.  Can someone please help?
HTML:

```
<div id="Background">
<img src="images/background/background.png">
</div>
```

CSS:

```
div#Background
{
 background-image:url('images/background/background.png')
 background-repeat:no-repeat;
}
```

Comment: Would be easier if you have a sample to play around. if you could put your result on http://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: For a start it appears both images are the same path.

Answer (score 1):

Here's how I'd do it. You'll need to give the surrounding div the dimentions of the background image:

**HTML**

```
<div class="background">
    <img class="logo" src="http://placehold.it/150x75/FF0000/FFF&text=Logo" alt="Company Name" />
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.background
{
    position:relative; /*Any child elements can now be positioned relative to this element*/
    background-image:url(http://placehold.it/750x150&text=background);
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    width:700px;    /*Width of background image*/
    height:150px;   /*Height of background image*/
}
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/8RC7U/

There are many different ways you can then position the logo:

*Margins*

```
.logo
{
    margin-top: 10px;
    margin-left: 10px;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/8RC7U/1/

*Absolute Positioning*

```
.logo
{
    position:absolute;
    top: 15px;
    right:30px;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/8RC7U/2/

and that's just for starters.

On a final note the following may be more accesible for screen readers and better for SEO:

**HTML - Include the company name as text**

```
<div class="background">
    <h2 class="logo">Company Name</h2>
</div>
```

**CSS - Shift the text off screen and use background image again**

```
.background
{
    position:relative;
    background-image:url(http://placehold.it/750x150&text=background);
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    width:700px;
    height:150px;
}

.logo
{
    text-indent:-9999px; /*Shift the text off screen*/
    width:150px; /*Width Of logo*/
    height:75px; /*Height of logo*/
    background-image:url(http://placehold.it/150x75/FF0000/FFF&text=Logo);
    margin: 10px 0 0 10px; /*Positioning top right bottom left*/
    display:inline-block;  /*Set to inline block so margins apply inside parent*/
}
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/8RC7U/3/

Answer (score 0):

**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/NqAA7/)**
**HTML**

```
 <div>
       <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150" class="img1">
       <img src="http://placehold.it/150x100" class="img2">
    <div>
```

**CSS**

```
div {
 position:relative;
}

.img1 {
  position:absolute;
  z-index:1;
  top:0; left:0;
}

.img2 {
  position:absolute;
  z-index:2;
  top:24px; left:100px;
    border: solid 2px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the **"background-image"** CSS attribute on a block-level element (,  etc.) for the background PNG, then place the PNG buttons inside that block element.

You can try Like this:

**CSS**

```
<style type="text/css">
    div#Background
    {
    background-image:url('images/background/background.png')
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    }
</style>
```

**HTML**

```
<div id="Background">
    <img src="images/background/background.png" />
</div>
```

If you have doubt let me know..

Answer (score 0):

One of the simple solution is use

```
z-index
```

make your logo's Z-index graterThan background Z-index e.g()

```
#background
{
   z-index:9
}
#logo
{
   z-index:99
}
```

This would help you accomplished what you want.

Hope that helps

Comment: z-index is a poor solution with the existing html. By default the parent element  will have a lower z-index than its' children.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to use only two images the best way to do it

have the div with the background, then load a image in side the div.

```
<div id="Background">
<img src="images/background/background.png">
</div>

#Background
{
 background-image:url('images/background/background.png')
 background-repeat:no-repeat;
}
```